# How can I iterate through this zipped table backwards?

Tags: python, loops

I have something like this table:

```
table = 
[[set(), {A}, set(), {B}], 
[{c}, set(), set(), {D}]]
```

I want to iterate through the columns so that in order I'm looking at B, D, set(), set(), A, set(), set(), C

I flipped my table using zip(*table) and now this:

```
table = zip(*table)
for word_index, row in enumerate(table):
  for index in range(len(row)):
    print(row[index])
```

allows me to iterate like set(), C, A, set(), set(), set(), B, D
Which is very close. But I want to also reverse.

zip(*table) does not allow me to call reversed(zip(*table))

How can I iterate through how I want? I don't really want to import Pandas or numpy if I can avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: What's the fastest way to zip right to left, and is there no builtin for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013071/python-whats-the-fastest-way-to-zip-right-to-left-and-is-there-no-builtin-for)

Comment: I looked at that question, but I couldn't get .reversed to work even after converting it to a list. The solution below works for m!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map `reversed` to the rows before passing them to zip:

```
table = [[set(), {"A"}, set(), {"B"}], [{"c"}, set(), set(), {"D"}]]
```

In pairs:

```
for s1,s2 in zip(*map(reversed,table)):
    print(s1,s2)  

{'B'} {'D'}
set() set()
{'A'} set()
set() {'c'}
```

Flattened:

```
flat = (s for ss in zip(*map(reversed,table)) for s in ss)
print(*flat)

{'B'} {'D'} set() set() {'A'} set() set() {'c'}
```

*Note that zip, map and reversed are all iterators so you really are iterating in the desired order (as opposed to creating reversed list for the rows or a temporary inverted matrix)*

Answer (score 0):

Similar to others, just a different notation `[::-1]` to reverse.

```py
for i in zip(*[i[::-1] for i in table]):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
table = [[set(), {'A'}, set(), {'B'}], [{'C'}, set(), set(), {'D'}]]
liste=[]
for obj1,obj2 in zip(*table[::-1]):
    liste.append(obj1)
    liste.append(obj2)
print(liste[::-1])
```